How can I write a plugin that will run on spotify?
I want to make a plugin to spotify for I don't want to see the picture when I going to listening to music
Is it possible?
I found website of spotify developer but it seem to be just for using spotify ob other app not to run plugin on spotify itself

You can make plugins for Spicetify, a powerful CLI tool to take control of the Spotify client.
